# GetFeatureInfo on TMS layer with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, tile-map-service

I'm using OpenLayers.Layer.TMS to display external layers that have a different projection than EPSG3857/EPSG900913.
I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.sumbera.com/2010/02/17/overlay-wms-on-google-in-openlayers/).

Now I can't use OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo or OpenLayers.Control.WMTSGetFeatureInfo controls so how to handle getFeatureInfo request with my TMS layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are no controls to handle GetFeatureInfo for TMS layers I created the url with all necessary parameters and made the request with OpenLayers.Request.GET.